# I am not able to get that why this error. And what is the solution for this

Tags: django

I am beginner so please bear silly questions

if i remove highlighted lines 1,2,3(+ static line) my localhost it shows normal django homepage but after adding these highlighted lines, it shows error

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/
Using the URLconf defined in portfolio.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order: 
              admin/ 
              ^media/(?P<path>.*)$ 
The empty path didn't match any of these. 
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

but admin page loads with no problem

```
#urls.py file

    from django.contrib import admin                    
    from django.urls import path
    from django.conf import settings                     **<----- 1**
    from django.conf.urls.static import static          **<----- 2** 
    
    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) **  <--- 3**
```

## settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL  = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Comment: Django standard names are `STATIC_URL` and `STATIC_ROOT.` Can you post the setup in `settings.py`

Comment: i have added settings.py code

Comment: Thanks found my mistake

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access root page of your app.

Your main urls.py, should look like this

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = = [
    path('admin/', admins.site.urls),
    path('', include("exampleapp.urls"),
]
```

Create another app, which will handle your root page using python manage.py startapp exampleapp

in exampleapp/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "exampleapp"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index)
]
```

In exampleapp/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def index(request):
    return render(request, "index.html", {})
```

Basically, in your app's root urls.py, you have not specifified the '/' route of your app or what you can call is the index of the app. You need to do that and the above is an example of it.

In your settings.py, add this, if you haven't:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

Comment: i missed adding second line but after adding it shows same error

Comment: I have edited the answer. Please go through it again.

Comment: then i need to create new index.html file.  Can't just it displays default django homepage

Comment: You were right i had not added any html file for homepage that's why it was showing error

Comment: Glad, I was able to help you out!